# JpaSagaStore in conjunction with Jackson unable to properly store state

Tags: axon

In a SpringBoot application, I have the following configuration:

```
axon:
  axonserver:
    servers: "${AXON_SERVER:localhost}"
  serializer:
    general: jackson
    messages: jackson
    events: jackson

logging.level:
  org.axonframework.modelling.saga: debug
```

Downsizing the scenario to bare minimum, the relevant portion of Saga class:

```
@Slf4j
@Saga
@ProcessingGroup("AuctionEventManager")
public class AuctionEventManagerSaga {
    @Autowired
    private transient EventScheduler eventScheduler;

    private ScheduleToken scheduleToken;
    private Instant auctionTimerStart;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "auctionEventId")
    protected void on(final AuctionEventScheduled event) {
        this.auctionTimerStart = event.getTimerStart();

        // Cancel any pre-existing previous job, since the scheduling thread might be lost upon a crash/restart of JVM.
        if (this.scheduleToken != null) {
            this.eventScheduler.cancelSchedule(this.scheduleToken);
        }

        this.scheduleToken = this.eventScheduler.schedule(
            this.auctionTimerStart,
            AuctionEventStarted.builder()
                .auctionEventId(event.getAuctionEventId())
                .build()
        );
    }

    @EndSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "auctionEventId")
    protected void on(final AuctionEventStarted event) {
        log.info(
            "[AuctionEventManagerSaga] Current state: {scheduleToken={}, auctionTimerStart={}}",
            this.scheduleToken,
            this.auctionTimerStart
        );
    }
}
```

In the final compiled class, we will end up having 4 properties: `log` (from `@Slf4j`), `eventScheduler` (transient, `@Autowired`), `scheduleToken` and `auctionTimerStart`.

For reference information, here is a sample of the general approach I've been using for both Command and Event classes:

```
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AuctionEventStarted.AuctionEventStartedBuilder.class)
public class AuctionEventStarted {
    AuctionEventId auctionEventId;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class AuctionEventStartedBuilder {}
}
```

When executing the code, you get the following output:

```
2020-05-12 15:40:01.180 DEBUG 1 --- [mandProcessor-4] o.a.m.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore   : Updating saga id c8aff7f7-d47f-4616-8a96-a40044cb7e3b as {}
```

As soon as the general serializer is changed to `xstream`, the content is serialized properly, but  I face another issue during deserialization, since I have `private static final class` Builder classes using Lombok.

So is there a way for Axon to handle these scenarios:

1- Axon to safely manage Jackson to ignore `@Autowired`, transient and static properties from `@Saga` classes? I've attempted to manually define `@JsonIgnore` at non-state properties and it still didn't work.

2- Axon to safely configure XStream to ignore inner classes (mostly Builder classes implemented as private static final)?

Thanks in advance,

---

**EDIT:** I'm pursuing a resolution using my preferred serializer: JSON. I attempted to modify the saga class and extend `JsonSerializer<AuctionEventManagerSaga>`. For that I implemented the methods:

```
    @Override
    public Class<AuctionEventManagerSaga> handledType() {
        return AuctionEventManagerSaga.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
        final AuctionEventManagerSaga value,
        final JsonGenerator gen,
        final SerializerProvider serializers
    ) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField("scheduleToken", value.eventScheduler);
        gen.writeObjectField("auctionTimerStart", value.auctionTimerStart);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
```

Right now, I have something being serialized, but it has nothing to do with the properties I've defined:

```
2020-05-12 16:20:01.322 DEBUG 1 --- [mandProcessor-0] o.a.m.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore   : Storing saga id c4b5d94c-7251-40a5-accf-332768b1cacd as {"delegatee":null,"unwrappingSerializer":false}
```

---

**EDIT 2** Decided to add more insight into the issue I experience when I switch general to use XStream (even though it's somewhat unrelated to the main issue described in the title).

Here is the issue it complains to me:

```
2020-05-12 17:08:06.495 DEBUG 1 --- [ault-executor-0] o.a.a.c.command.AxonServerCommandBus     : Received command response [message_identifier: "79631ffb-9a87-4224-bed3-a957730dced7"
error_code: "AXONIQ-4002"
error_message {
  message: "No converter available\n---- Debugging information ----\nmessage             : No converter available\ntype                : jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread\nconverter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter\nmessage[1]          : Unable to make field private static final jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.UNSAFE accessible: module java.base does not \"opens jdk.internal.misc\" to unnamed module @7728643a\n-------------------------------"
  location: "1@600b5b87a922"
  details: "No converter available\n---- Debugging information ----\nmessage             : No converter available\ntype                : jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread\nconverter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter\nmessage[1]          : Unable to make field private static final jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.UNSAFE accessible: module java.base does not \"opens jdk.internal.misc\" to unnamed module @7728643a\n-------------------------------"
}
request_identifier: "2f7020b1-f655-4649-bbe0-d6f458b3c2f3"
]
2020-05-12 17:08:06.505  WARN 1 --- [ault-executor-0] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'ACommandClassDispatchedFromSaga' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(No converter available
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No converter available
type                : jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread
converter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
message[1]          : Unable to make field private static final jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.UNSAFE accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.misc" to unnamed module @7728643a
-------------------------------)
```

Still no luck on resolving this...

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on Axon systems where the only used `Serializer` implementation was the `JacksonSerializer` too. Mind you though, this is not what the Axon team recommends. For messages (i.e. commands, events and queries) it makes perfect sense to use JSON as the serialized format. But switching the general `Serializer` to jackson means you have to litter your domain logic (e.g. your Saga) with Jackson specifics "to make it work".

Regardless, backtracking to my successful use case of jackson-serialized-sagas. In this case we used the correct match of JSON annotations on the fields we desired to take into account (the actual state) and to ignore the one's we didn't want deserialized (with either `transient` or `@JsonIgnore`). Why both do not seem to work in your scenario is not entirely clear at this stage.

What I do recall is that the referenced project's team very clearly decided against Lombok due to "overall weirdnes" when it comes to de-/serialization. As a trial it thus might be worth to not use **any** Lombok annotations/logic in the Saga class and see if you can de-/serialize it correctly in such a state.

If it does work at that moment, I think you have found your culprit for diving in further search.

I know this isn't an exact answer, but I hope it helps you regardless!
Might be worthwhile to share the repository where this problems occurs in; might make the problem clearer for others too.

### JKD16+ and Serializer impact Update

Since JDK16 and up, reflective access to the base of Java has been further closed off. This has made XStream's solution towards de-/serialization of unknown objects through *heavy* reflections far from optimal.

As it stands, the XStream project itself is doubtful about the life of XStream in the future, as seen in [this](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/262) issue.

Although I know my original reply suggests the use of Axon's `XStreamSerializer` for anything other than events and/or messages, that mindset shifted due to the above.

As such, using Axon Framework's `JacksonSerializer` throughout, at least for more recent versions of the JDK, is advisable. The downside is the requirement for objects like your Saga and Aggregate (since it's the snapshot) classes to support de-/serialization through Jackson.

However, given the lifespan of XStream is unsure, I feel this shift is justified. Furthermore, I figured this update would be valuable for others to read too.

Comment: I ended up finding the issue in XStream. There was one field that was not `transient`, and now XStream serialization worked like a charm. 
To use a mixed scenario of JSON for messages and events, and XStream for general it would be challenging, as events would require to have both Jackson and XStream annotations to behave properly. I switched everything to XStream for now, as the company I work for only uses Java and it would be ok to decode the events using XStream. Not the greatest solution, as I really wanted (and hoped) JSON would be supported properly out of the box.

Comment: If you using Jackson for Events/Messages and XStream for the rest than there should be no need to have both annotations on the events since the events *will not* be serialized by XStream in such a scenario. I've mixed both serializers in plenty a project without requiring dedicated XStream support specifics. Would you mind elaborating why this is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue #2 when using XStream as general serializer.
One of the Sagas had an `@Autowired` dependency property that was not `transient`.
XStream was throwing some cryptic message, but we managed to track the problem and address it.

As for JSON support, we had no luck. We ended up switched everything to XStream for now, as the company only uses Java and it would be ok to decode the events using XStream.

Not the greatest solution, as we really wanted (and hoped) JSON would be supported properly out of the box. Mind you, this is in conjunction with using *Lombok* which caused for the nuisance in this case.

Comment: That you weren't able to use a mix of the `XStreamSerializer` and the `JacksonSerializer` is kinda funky if you ask me. I've worked on and seen plenty a project where events/messages used the `JacksonSerializer` and the default of XStream was utilized for Saga's, Tokens and Snapshots. I'd be curious to understand why you weren't able to achieve this conjunction @Guilherme, as now you make it seem like Axon lacks in a functionality which I know it does include.

Comment: I might have forgot to be more explicit... mixing XStream with Jackson in conjunction with Lombok.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Guilherme. That's valuable info for other people who might end up on this issue of yours :-)